# IIS Log files are not getting generated for the "SharePoint Web Services" webapplication in SharePoint - 2010?

Tags: logging, iis

IIS Log files are not getting generated for the "SharePoint Web Services" webapplication in SharePoint - 2010, even though Logging is enabled at the IIS level.

Is that an expected behavior? or this there nothing can be done to trace IIS logs for the "SharePoint Web Services" webapplication?

Comment: This is not expected behaviour, logs should exist for a web application's IIS web site and are a critical troubleshooting tool.

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint Web Services use WCF which runs "side-by-side" with ASP.NET within IIS and thus do not get logged within the HTTP pipeline. 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa702682.aspx

I tried setting `<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />` in the web.config, but it didn't seem to help.

I successfully enabled WCF tracing by Following https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025.aspx.  I then had great fun Using Service Trace Viewer for Viewing Correlated Traces and Troubleshooting (h ttps://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa751795.aspx).  Unfortunately, its too verbose to leave on and is not as easy as IIS web logs.